# TraceContext in a .NET Framework (4.8) WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, trace

While Microsoft assures backward compatibility and yes in .NET Core and .NET 5 the integration is seamless, in .NET Framework it seams not to the case.

I've set:

```
 Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
       Activity.ForceDefaultIdFormat = true;
```

In the Application_Start():

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
        Activity.ForceDefaultIdFormat = true;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    }
}
```

as well as the Owin start up but to no avail.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TraceContextInsightsFW.Startup))]
```

Anyone experienced the same issue, or has successfully got the integration going?

The issue is that in .netFramework as apposed to .NetCore, and .NET5, the W3C tracecontext correlation is lost.
In the controller recieving a the request, the Activity.Current losses the parentId and ParentSpanId.

Example: A controller recieving a valid W3C Format request:

The origen Activity Id:
00-975e19118f72821cd68475169c35efb3-476977b663199710-00

.netframework **Activity.Current** values:

> ParentId = "589b789e32fbfb9f20092c6a06b898f3"
> ParentSpanId ={0000000000000000}

.netCore **Activity.Current** values:

> ParentId = "00-975e19118f72821cd68475169c35efb3-476977b663199710-00"
> ParentSpanId = {476977b663199710}

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what your issue is?